# How to close a while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I thought my code was correct but when I ran it, my output statements at the bottom wouldnt produce. I'm asking the keyboard to enter any number and then to end by entering -1. My while loop includes adding numbers, creating a sum, as well as giving the amount of even numbers. When I test my code I've been entering just 1,2,3,4 hoping to produce 4 total numbers. 2 even, and a sum of 10. Why isnt' my code getting to the print statements?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number. Enter -1 to stop    program.");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int counter = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int sum = 0; 
    while (num != -1)
    {
        counter += 1;
        sum += num; 
        if (num%2 == 0)
        {
            even +=1;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("You have entered "+ counter + "number(s)");
    System.out.println("You have entered "+ even + "even numbers");
    System.out.println("The sum for the numbers you entered is "+ sum);

}
```

Comment: you never modify the value of `num`, hence if `num != -1`, this will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Does that mean I need to ask scanner for another int in my while loop?

Comment: Yes you need to ask scanner for another int to input a new value. You can do this at the end part of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never get the input again so the loop runs infinitely. You need to get the value again.

```
while (num != -1)
{
    ...

    num = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to but says i can't accept an answer until 10mins is up

Answer (score 0):

num gets set before you enter the loop.

So, when does the num change inside the while loop? It doesn't. That's why your code won't exit the loop.

I suggest moving the

```
num = sc.nextInt();
```

inside the loop.